# How to have sendmail write server IP in headers

Tags: sendmail

I'm experiencing a lot of bounced emails after a recent change in hosts. What is happening, and may very well be correct, is that I will send mail from my MTA at home through my server and the server authenticates via STARTTLS and relays the mail using my home IP address.

I don't recall this behavior from our old server. What I recall is that the server's IP address would be used in the from header.

Is there a way to use the server's IP address in place of my home IP? What I find is that most dynamic IPs are blacklisted, causing many of my mails to bounce. I'm not sure what I need to do this. Is this masquerading I want? I do not want to use a smarthost for this.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

I have two bounced messages I'd like to post.

```
The original message was received at Fri, 2 Mar 2012 10:45:35 -0800 (PST)
from cpe-170-31-105-69.res.rr.com [170.31.105.69]

   ----- The following addresses had permanent fatal errors -----
<xxxxxxxxxx@messaging.sprintpcs.com>
    (reason: 554 lnxipc002-in.nmcc.sprintspectrum.com)

   ----- Transcript of session follows -----
... while talking to mx.messaging.sprintpcs.com.:
<<< 554 lnxipc002-in.nmcc.sprintspectrum.com
554 5.0.0 Service unavailable
```

The last one is:

```
The original message was received at Thu, 1 Mar 2012 11:02:35 -0800 (PST)
from cpe-170-31-105-69.res.rr.com [170.31.105.69]

   ----- The following addresses had permanent fatal errors -----
<johndoe@corp.com>
    (reason: 554 Transaction Failed Spam Message not queued.)

   ----- Transcript of session follows -----
... while talking to mail2.corp.com.:
>>> DATA
<<< 554 Transaction Failed Spam Message not queued.
554 5.0.0 Service unavailable
```

Comment: This Question is Off-Topic per [sf]'s FAQ: "and it is not about…Anything in a home setting". [su] covers such topics however, this Question has been migrated there.

Comment: Thanks for putting this post where it belongs, Chris. I wasn't sure which site to post this on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. An MTA should **never** change exiting headers unless it has some extraordinarily good reason, this is not one.
2. That the e-mail originated from a dynamic IP has almost nothing to do with the next hope accepting the e-mail.

   I run a mail server at my house. It relays e-mail to a VPS I have, which forward e-mail appropriately. I've never had a single e-mail bounce because of the home server with a dynamic IP (which **is** listed in any PBLs I've looked through). Also the home server writes in a Received header for the internal IP of the MUA that originated the e-mail, or in the case of webmail is yet another IP address (and the webmail software writes it's own Received header in concerning the web browser which logged in; and if there's a proxy in the middle it's information gets in there too)

Comment: Chris, I'm not following you completely. Maybe what I'm asking is not possible but I'm going to ask in simple terms since I don't have all that much experience with sendmail. What I would like is for the email headers to show that the email I sent from my client, originated from my server and not my client; as if the server itself sent the mail. Is this possible?

Comment: @Muzz - in the DSN, except DSN-text quoted, you have (most probably) original message, which produce bounce. Read it's headers!

Comment: @LazyBadger, I'm not following you. Can you be more specific? I'm not privy to sendmail at all.

Comment: @Muzz - in received bounce e-mail, with you read in your MUA (no relation to sendmail at all), **you have attachment** - your original mail. Save it, open, read headers of e-mail

Comment: @Muzz, while it's technically possible yes; no you should not do that. I thought #1 was completely clear: but to reiderate, an MTA should **never** lie. The origin of your e-mail does not effect next-hop delivery; the "problem" you think exist, does not. If you're having problems they are elsewhere. Try putting the IP of your server into http://whatismyipaddress.com/blacklist-check; see what it finds. If that's clean you'll need to ask the postmaster for the domain you're trying to send to, they should have details of the problem.

Comment: @ChrisS, Thanks for the help. Using the link you've provided, I've verified that my server IP is not listed in any of the lists. However, my home IP is listed in two of them. Would this possibly be the reason for the bounces? This was what originally made me want to change the Received-From portion of the header. I guess I can send an email to the postmaster of the domain and ask them why my mail is bouncing. If there is anything else you can think for me to check in the mean time, please let me know. Thanks, Chris.

Comment: @ChrisS, Also I should mention that I followed the advice of InchargeOfIT in the post below and added SPF records for the domain but has not corrected the issue.

Comment: The previous hop has no bearing on the next hop in e-mail delivery. The only RBL-factor severs consider are where the current connection is coming from, not where the e-mail started and not any received headers currently in the inbound e-mail. Other factors are considered, and there's a possibility the destination in question is not using a popular/public blacklist. If I had to guess the problem is the content of your message, but that's just an off-handed guess. SPF records absolutely help in general; no guarantee for specific situations. Same for DKIM, though that's much more complicated.

Comment: I'm still sticking with the "contact the postmaster, they'll know". I really hate when MTAs don't specify *why* an e-mail is bouncing... if you ever get the chance to berate the postmaster for their crappy DSNs, please do so.

Comment: @ChrisS, thanks for all your help. I'll send an email to the postmaster and see what they have to say about it. Also, I will tell them about their info, or lack thereof in the DSN. I'll credit you for the answer, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The receiving MTA will look at the connecting MTA's ip accept/reject based on that, not the ip address of the originator. Otherwise no one's email would get anywhere. This is all in the headers.

Do you have a DSN of a bounced message ? If you are indeed using sendmail it should give you all relevant info as to why the message bounced.

Most likely the ip of your new server is in some RBLs and that is why but without the actual DSN one can only speculate. If it is greek to you, post it.

Comment: Thanks kls, sendmail was never one of my strong points. I've already verified that my IP is clean and is not listed in any RBLs. I'm going to post one of the DSNs in an edit, up top. Thanks for looking and the help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you relaying through your ISP or another provider? If you local MTA is delivering mail directly to the internet, then you would be subjected to common spam checks (e.g., SPF records, reverse DNS lookups).

In postfix for example, you would set the relayhost directive to the IP address of your provider. A google example: https://www.wormly.com/blog/2008/11/05/relay-gmail-google-smtp-postfix/

Comment: I have this server in a data center and I'm not using a smarthost if that's what you mean. I have TLS configured in sendmail so when I use my ISP at home, I authenticate to the server and send the mail. It seems however, I am being blacklisted by Sprint and another organization. Both bounce the mail back to me with a 554 status code. See: `reason: 554 lnxipc002-in.nmcc.sprintspectrum.com`

Comment: @Muzz They could be rejecting you for a number of reasons: virus detection, poor domain ratings, spf records, etc. and that specific reject reason is too vague to know. Are there any other 554's in your logs with a more descriptive reason? Out of curiosity, have you verified your SPF records? This tool can be helpful if you have not http://www.kitterman.com/spf/validate.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. Since the host has offered to host my DNS, I didn't have access to write an SPF however, thanks to the link you've provided, it appears that there are no SPF records found. `No type SPF records found.` I know if I ask them to add it, they will. Thanks for this tip.

Comment: I just requested that my host add an SPF record for me. I'm sure that will be done within the hour.

Comment: I would guess that this is your problem. Also make sure you have reverse DNS entries for your domain as well.

Comment: Thanks InChargeOfIT. I already have in-addr.arpa records that return to my IP so I think I'm OK there. I just heard back from my host and they are adding the SPF records now. I'm not 100% certain on this but I asked them to add one for each A, MX and PTR record. Am I missing anything else with regard to SPF? BTW: Love your moniker; wish I would have thought of it. :)

Comment: Add an SPF for each domain that will be sending mail on your behalf. The process is the receiving mail server checks the ip address of the sending server, does a reverse lookup, looks for SPF/TXT records that states the sending ip address or domain is authorized to send the email. An example bind entry may be:`@     IN      TXT     "v=spf1 ip4:192.200.20.0/24 ip4:74.200.200.0/24 include:support.zendesk.com -all"` and `@     IN      SPF     "v=spf1 ip4:192.200.20.0/24 ip4:74.200.200.0/24 include:support.zendesk.com -all"` This would allow two subnets to send mail as well as zendesk.

Comment: It's good practice to create an `IN TXT` and `IN SPF` record for each domain (e.g. company.com, mail.company.com, etc)

Comment: Well, my host added the SPF records but my mail is still bouncing back. Would you have any other ideas what would be causing this? I appreciate any insight you may be able to offer.